# How do I remove duplicate subgoals in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

In Isabelle, one occasionally reaches a scenario where there are duplicate subgoals. For example, imagine the following proof script:

```
lemma "a ∧ a"
  apply (rule conjI)
```

with goals:

```
proof (prove): step 1

goal (2 subgoals):
 1. a
 2. a
```

Is there any way to eliminate the duplicate subgoal in-place, so proofs need not be repeated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ML-level tactic `distinct_subgoals_tac` in `Pure/tactic.ML` removes duplicate subgoals, and can be used as follows:

```
lemma "a ∧ a"
  apply (rule conjI)
  apply (tactic {* distinct_subgoals_tac *})
```

leaving:

```
proof (prove): step 2

goal (1 subgoal):
 1. a
```

There does not appear to be a way without dropping into the ML world, unfortunately.

Comment: What is so unfortunate about that? It looks rather succinct to me. Also note that in structured proofs (as opposed to apply-scripts) you can use `by fact` to discharge a goal that has already been proven before (of course you have to state it explicitly once more, but that can be shortened by using abbreviations or term patterns `(is "p1 ... pN")`).

Comment: Explaining the `tactic` syntax to newcomers is what I meant by "unfortunate". More generally, I understand that creating a lemma for the duplicate fact is preferable. But often tools such as Schirmer's [`vcg`](http://afp.sourceforge.net/entries/Simpl.shtml)  leave one with a mess of subgoals that one would rather not clag back into the proof script.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar behavior as a side effect of the `subst` method applied to any theorem, and for example `refl`. Then `apply (subst refl)` do indeed remove the duplicate subgoals.

It's not a bug, It's a feature ;-).

Comment: This unintended behaviour will probably disappear in Isabelle2021, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63657976/subst-refl-closing-duplicate-subgoals-whats-going-on/63658319#63658319 .

Answer (score 1):

Adding to davidg's answer, if one does not want to use `tactic` for whatever reason, it is easy enough to turn `distinct_subgoals_tac` into a method:

```
method_setup distinct_subgoals =
  ‹Scan.succeed (K (SIMPLE_METHOD distinct_subgoals_tac))›

lemma P and P and P
  (* here there are three goals P *)
  apply distinct_subgoals
  (* now there is only one goal P *)
```