# Subst refl closing duplicate subgoals. What's going on?

Tags: isabelle

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608399/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-subgoals-in-isabelle) thread Mathieu demonstrates that `subst refl` closes duplicate subgoals. How/Why is it doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not completely sure, but a quick look at the code suggests that `subst` calls `distinct_subgoals_tac` for some reason and does not restrict it to the subgoal it is working on:

```
fun eqsubst_tac ctxt occs thms i st =
  let val nprems = Thm.nprems_of st in
    if nprems < i then Seq.empty else
    let
      val thmseq = Seq.of_list thms;
      fun apply_occ occ st =
        thmseq |> Seq.maps (fn r =>
          eqsubst_tac' ctxt
            (skip_first_occs_search occ searchf_lr_unify_valid) r
            (i + (Thm.nprems_of st - nprems)) st);
      val sorted_occs = Library.sort (rev_order o int_ord) occs;
    in
      Seq.maps distinct_subgoals_tac (Seq.EVERY (map apply_occ sorted_occs) st)
    end
  end;
```

That does not seem like intended behaviour to me – probably an oversight in the implementation of `subst`. I'll write an email to the mailing list to ask about it.

Comment: The question is available at https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2020-August/msg00089.html

Comment: Makarius now changed the behaviour of `subst` in order to not affect other subgoals now, as of revision `e5fcbf6dc687` of the development version of Isabelle. https://isabelle-dev.sketis.net/rISABELLEe5fcbf6dc687